# Detect endianness of binary file data

Tags: c++, file-handling, endianness

Recently I was (again) reading about 'endian'ness. I know how to identify the endianness of host, as there are lots of post on SO, and also I have seen [this](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-endianc/), which I think is pretty good resource.

However, one thing I like to know is to how to detect the endianness of input binary file. For example, I am reading a binary file (using `C++`) like following:

```
ifstream mydata("mydata.raw", ios::binary);

short value;
char buf[sizeof(short)];
int dataCount = 0;

short myDataMat[DATA_DIMENSION][DATA_DIMENSION];
while (mydata.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&buf), sizeof(buf)))
{
    memcpy(&value, buf, sizeof(value));
    myDataMat[dataCount / DATA_DIMENSION][dataCount%DATA_DIMENSION] = value;
    dataCount++;
}
```

I like to know how I can detect the endianness in the `mydata.raw`, and whether endianness affects this program anyway.

Additional Information:

- I am only manipulating the data in `myDataMat` using mathematical operations, and no pointer operation or bitwise operation is done on the data).
- My machine (host) is little endian.

Comment: You cannot *detech* endianness of a binary file. Just use `htons` etc when writing data to the file and `ntohs` etc when reading it

Comment: In short: You cannot.

Comment: *I like to know how I can detect the endianness...* You cannot *detect* it. Either the file itself contains some indication of the endianness it uses, or you're short of luck. If you read `0x2a00`, you cannot determine if it is `42` (little endian) or `10752` (big endian).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is impossible to "detect" the endianity of data in general. Just like it is impossible to detect whether the data is an array of 4 byte integers, or twice that many 2 byte integers. Without any knowledge about the representation, raw data is just a mass of meaningless bits.

However, with some extra knowledge about the data representation, it become possible. Some examples:

- Most file formats mandate particular endianity, in which case this is never a problem.
- Unicode text files may optionally start with a [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). Same idea can be implemented by other data representations.
- Some file formats contain a [checksum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum). You can guess one endianity, and if the checksum does not match, try again with another endianity. It will be unlikely that the checksum matches with wrong interpretation of the data.
- Sometimes you can make guesses based on the data. Is the temperature outside `33'554'432` degrees, or maybe `2`? You can pick the endianity that represents sane data. Of course, this type of guesswork fails miserably, when the aliens invade and start melting our planet.

Answer (score 5):

You can't tell.

The endianness transformation is essentially an operator E(x) on a number `x` such that x = E(E(x)). So you don't know "which way round" the `x` elements are in your file.